# Can't set up IIS Web Server on Server 2008 x64 correctly (what have I missed?)

Tags: windows-server-2008, configuration, iis-7.5, session

Using a VM I installed Windows 2008 Server x64 and as the image below shows, added the IIS Role

[image]
<sub>(source: [balexandre.com](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-13_1339.png))</sub>

[full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixLk7.png)

and assigned all role features of IIS

[image]
<sub>(source: [balexandre.com](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-13_1343.png))</sub>

[full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnvjf.png)

But if I have an ASP.NET (aspx) page that does (C#)

```
Session["test-session"] = "A";
```

and read in other page

I always get nothing!

**NOTE:** I do have an entire ASP.NET web application, the example above is to be succinct and explicit on what is the problem I'm facing.

Can anyone know what do I have to do to the Server, so I can use the **Session variables**?

All help is greatly appreciated, 
**Thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that is **something with Internet Explorer 8** and the absurd Security stuff.

As I installed Firefox and everything is ok.

I will post what are the setting to disable, maybe it could help anyone.